# How do I position the h1 element in relation to others?

Tags: html, css

I need to correctly (no hardcode) position the h1 element using grid css or flex.
All of these elements are stored in equal sized columns. In one line.
When the screen gets smaller I need to put element1 & element2 below the h1 test.
The specifics of the task does not allow using @media in css for various screen extensions. Therefore, I am writing here, because I do not understand how to do this.

[I need this position of the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMMIW.png)

```
<article id="MyContainer">
      <div>
        <h1>SOME TEXT</h1> ----- i need to change this 
        <div id="buttonsZone">
          <button id="button1" class="btn-secondary">
          <span>
            <img src="myTest.svg">
          </span>
            <span>element 1</span>
          </button>
          <button id="button2" class="btn-secondary">
          <span>
            <img src="myPicture.svg">
          </span>
            <span>element 2</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
 </article>


article div:first-of-type {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 
article .btn-secondary {
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h1>
    h1 text
  </h1>
  <div>
    <button>
      button 1
    </button>
    <button>
      button 2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, take a look at this helpful [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox).